# How to clone an ol3 style?

Tags: openlayers

I can't find any simple way to clone an ol3 style.  There is no `clone()` method and creating a style from a style (`new ol.style.Style(style)`) doesn't do it.  `JSON.stringify` doesn't produce anything usable, either.

Is there any ol3 code I might be overlooking for cloning styles?

Comment: Easier cloning has been added to 3.19; https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.19.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from ol-debug.js:

```
var typeOf = function(obj){
    return ({}).toString.call(obj)
        .match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
};
function cloneObject(obj){
    var type = typeOf(obj);
    if (type == 'object' || type == 'array') {
        if (obj.clone) {
            return obj.clone();
        }
        var clone = type == 'array' ? [] : {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            clone[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
        }
        return clone;
    }
    return obj;
}
var circle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [0,0,0,.9],
            width: 3
        })
    })
});
var cloned = cloneObject(circle);
console.info(cloned.getImage().getOpacity());
```

Comment: This would be fine for a JSON object and would probably work but it is unsafe; it's copying methods and internal state; unfortunately, there is also no clone on fill, stroke, etc.

Comment: Actually it does clone fill and stroke - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/529Lk9c5/).

Comment: It does it but they don't *have* a clone on them.  Your code would probably work but it's not the "simple way" I was looking for.